# I am getting error in this simple piece of code while using super function

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I have tried changing the code a little but it didn't work.
Here's the code anyway.

```py
class Car:
    def __init__(self,model,name,year):
        self.name=name
        self.model=model
        self.year=year
        self.Class='normal'
        self.odometer=0
    def descriptive_name(self):
        return f'{self.year} {self.name} {self.model}'
    def type(self):
        return self.Class
    def odometer_reading(self):
        return self.odometer

class Battery:
    def __init__(self):
        self.capacity='75 kwh'
    def get_capacity(self):
        return self.capacity

class Electric_car:
    def __init__(self,model,name,year):
        super(Car()).__init__(model,name,year)
        self.battery=Battery()
        self.Class='Electric_car'
    def my_battrey(self):
        return self.battery.get_capacity()
```

The code above is in the same directory as the code below.
Name the code above as main.py and in the same directory write the code below in new file and try running it.

```
import main
my_scorpio=main.Car('s','scorpio',2019)
print(my_scorpio.descriptive_name())
print(my_scorpio.odometer_reading())
print(my_scorpio.type())
my_tesla=main.Electric_car('s','Tesla',2019)
print(my_tesla.descriptive_name())
print(my_tesla.odometer_reading)
print(my_tesla.type())
print(my_tesla.my_battrey())
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: to inherit use: `class ClassName(InheritedClass):` and then use `super()` also You might as well then use: `InheritedClass.__init__(self, attributes)`

Comment: If you use `super` you should have a superclass.

Comment: `class Electric_car(Car):`  (I'd rename it to `class ElectricCar(Car):`) + `super().__init__(model, name, year)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
class Electric_car:
    def __init__(self,model,name,year):
        super(Car()).__init__(model,name,year)
```

I would guess from your title that this is the issue at hand.

In python you have to say explicitly that ElectricCar inherits from Car using this syntax

```py
class Electric_car(Car):
    def __init__(self,model,name,year):
        # this will give you the bound super object
        # from the inheritance Car > ElectricCar
        super(Car, self).__init__(model,name,year)
```

Then using `super(Car, self)` would know where to look for in the inheritance tree.

As pointed out in the comments you could also go for `super(ElectricCar, self)` as it is true that `isinstance(self, ElectricCar)`.

The error here was not setting up the inheritance tree by specifying that
the ElectricCar is a subclass of a Car and therefore you can't get that
far!

Without the inheritance bit then `isinstance(self, Car)` would be false as
self is of type `ElectricCar` which does not inherit from `Car`!

I really suggest reading the documentation for [`super`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) though because it explains what is happening when you use it!

Comment: Wouldn't it be `super(Electric_car, self).__init__(...)`? In python3 you can omit the type and use `super().__init__(...)`

Comment: yes, you are correct. super called with two arguments could also work like that. `super(type, obj)` returns the bound super object whenever `isinstace(obj, type)` so as any ElectricCar is an instance of a ElectricCar it would work. As we want to use the parent method we can also put Car there as it satisfies `isinstance(self, Car)` because of inheritance.

Comment: If you put `Car` in, it is valid but will not run the `Car.__init__` method. It'll run the next class up the inheritance order from `Car`, in this case that's `object` and is a no-op.

Answer (score 1):

The right way (old style) to call super is:

```
super(Electric_car, self).__init__(model,name,year)
```

Or simply (in Python 3.x):

```
super().__init__(model,name,year)
```